# Sub botões no dataTables Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou usando o plugin DataTable (https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables).
E preciso fazer com que os botões de exportar sejam subitens,onde haverá um icone de exportar e ao clicar neste será listado ( abaixo ) as opções ( CSV, PRINT, XLS).

Segue abaixo o código que estou usando, mas o mesmo não funciona os subitens, mas o botão principal sim.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp')
            .withButtons([
                'copy',
                'print', 
                {'sExtends': 'collection',
                 'sButtonText': 'Save',
                 'aButtons': ['csv', 'xls', 'pdf']
                }
            ])
            .withOption('info',false)
            .withOption('lengthChange',false);
    }
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Segue a forma como resolvi:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withLanguageSource('js/plugins/dataTables/pt.json')
            .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp')
            .withButtons([
                { extend:'collection', text: '<i class="fa fa-download"></i>', buttons: ['copy', 'csv', ] }, 
                { text: '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>' }
            ])
            .withOption('info',false)
            .withOption('lengthChange',false);
    }
```

Utilizando o `withButtons`, adicionei um objeto contendo a `extend 'Collection', text` que é o texto apresentado e buttons onde será listado os subitens.